# template vs regular function ambiguity - UB?

Tags: c++

```
template<typename T> T f(T i) { return i+1; }
int f(int i) { return i-1; }

f(2);
```

Is this undefined behaviour (note that `int f(int)` is not a specialization) ? If yes, then please point out where standard carries such case.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding what UB is...

Comment: By `UB`, do you mean *ambiguous* ? Either way, no. it isn't

Comment: By UB i mean something, that is not defined by standard. Ofc if it is defined somehow, I'm still willing to know :)

Comment: @Criss The proper term for this is "unspecified".

Comment: Here is the section to read: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution   _"...Before overload resolution begins, the functions selected by name lookup and template argument deduction are combined to form the set of candidate functions (the exact criteria depend on the context in which overload resolution takes place, see below). ..."_ and keep reading.

Comment: @Rakete1111 oh, ok, thanks. But the case above isn't *unspecified behaviour*, right?

Comment: @Criss No, fortunately it is not :)

Comment: @RichardCritten Thank you, this should be an answer :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not UB and not even ambiguous, it is just [overload resolution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution):

both are exact match, but one is template function whereas the other is not:

`int f(int)` is selected.

Comment: In the case where you actually want to do this (have a specific different function `f` for type `int`), what is the difference between template specialization (`template<> int f(int i) { return i-1; }`) and overloading that function (as done int he question)? Is there any advantage on using either of them? Or is it (as I suspect) the exact same thing?

Comment: @apalomer: you might ask this question as question instead of as comment. In OP's example, it would be mostly the same but things might be more complicated as partial specialization is not possible with template function. A common example is to handle `T`, `T*` and `int*`.

Comment: Not necessary to ask it as a question. After digging some bit I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7108033/template-specialization-vs-function-overloading) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911031/class-template-specialization-vs-function-overloading) qustions and answers which talk about that topic. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 6):

There is no ambiguity here. If there is an invocation of `f` with an `int`, the non-template version of the overload will always be chosen as long as both declarations are visible at the point of use.